# Function for Post Creation plugin for Gravity Forms

Tags: php, functions, plugin-gravity-forms

```
add_action('gform_after_submission_33', 'customize_submission_values_for_custom_post_type', 10, 2);
function customize_submission_values_for_custom_post_type($entry, $form) {
    if ($form['id'] !=  33) return;

    $post_id = rgar($entry, 'post_id');

    // Debugging: Check if post_id is set
    if (!$post_id) {
        error_log('Post ID is not set');
        return;
    }

    $field_95_value = rgar($entry, '95');
    $field_35_value = rgar($entry, '35');
    $sp_title_value = !empty($field_95_value) ? $field_95_value : $field_35_value;

    if (!$sp_title_value) {
        error_log('sp_title_value is not set');
        return;
    }

    // Update the custom field
    $result = update_post_meta($post_id, 'sp_title', $sp_title_value);

    if (!$result) {
        error_log('Failed to update sp_title');
    }
}
```

I am getting error Post ID is not set.. I am trying to update a custom field in a custom post type. Using the Post Creation plugin for Gravity Forms.